# How can I override the appearance of embedded Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm redesigning a Squarespace site for a client who owns a cooking school. She uses an external booking site (Fareharbor) to manage her classes which are then embedded into the site using JavaScript widget. The embedded listings don't match the style of the rest of the site, which looks really unprofessional, so I want to update the styles to make them look better. I tried modifying it in the CSS stylesheet (both in page and for the whole site) and it did nothing (clearly the script takes priority). I've looked around and people have said there's a way to do it using JQuery or straight JavaScript, but while I'm pretty adept at following code instructions and have a little JS experience, I'm pretty new to this so I don't actually know where I would put whatever code I use to change it.

So my question is:
1) What is the best way to override the default appearance of the embedded script?
2) If the answer involves using JavaScript/JQuery to modify the appearance of the original script, how do I do that? (What is the code, and where do I put it).

The page I'm trying to modify is figcookingschool.com/classes (currently working on the first embed, with the pictures – assuming the answer to this will help me with the second!) and the code I was given to embed the JavaScript is:

```
<script src="https://fareharbor.com/embeds/script/items/figcookingschool/?full-items=yes&fallback=simple"></script>
```

One of the many things I want to do is change the border-radius to 0 on each box so if you want something to use as an example, that's a good one ;) Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Without knowing how the script does embed the content into your page (e.g. whether is uses an `iframe` or not), and without knowing how the script applies the css styles it is not possible to tell how you should/can solve that.

Comment: Agree with @t.niese. Use your browser's "Inspector" to check whether the content generated by the script is an `iframe`. If it is, you're out of luck, which would explain why it didn't work. If it isn't, continue to use the inspector to determine which selectors you need to use. Note that this leaves you at the mercy of FareHarbor. It is likely they will change the content generated by the script, and your CSS may no longer work.

Comment: It does appear to be an iframe. Is there anyway at all to override that? Or am I totally screwed?

Comment: In similar situations I've utilized APIs provided by the company in question to create something similar to what the widget provided but less intrusively and under my control. It looks like fareharbor does have an API but the documentation looked limited: https://fareharbor.com/help/integrations/external-integration-api/

Comment: The farharbor code is definitely injecting an iframe: https://image.prntscr.com/image/WskIzI8vSkqeRwlrjtg6eQ.png

Comment: Im not sure this will be possible unless fareharbor provides a mechanism to apply custom css (I couldnt find such a feature). If the iframe's content were hosted on the same domain, ie your friends site, you could just do `$('iframe').contents().find('.item-grid-block').css('border-radius', '0px');` but as you'll see, this wont work here due to browser security features, ie you'll get `Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.figcookingschool.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` because the embedded content is hosted on a different domain

Comment: Looking [here](https://fareharbor.com/help/website/integrating-with-fareharbor/links-and-embeds/#embedded-grid-of-items) fareharbor states "*Note: Although there are several ways to modify the content of your embedded calendar, the calendar stylesheet itself (colors, fonts, etc.) is not currently customizable.*" presumably this applies to the class lists as well as that section doesnt list such a capability